# OnClick of Checkbox selecting row and Open the Row on Button Click with existing data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, popup

I m stucked here very much and it is going some serious.

I have a Gridview which I am using to show the data from the backend. What I did is For inserting the data, I have made a button on top of the Gridview to add the data in the gridview.

Like this:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-prm" Text="Add" Width="75" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="AddNew" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

The same is been done for `Edit` part also.

I have added a checkbox to select the row for the gridview.See my gridview code for better understanding,

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCSRPageData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="grdCSRPageData_DataBound" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="hoverTable"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDeleting="grdCSRPageData_RowDeleting" 
                PageSize="5" ShowFooter="true" OnRowEditing="grdCSRPageData_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdCSRPageData_RowUpdating" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="grdCSRPageData_RowCancelingEdit">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" BackColor="#f5f5f5"/>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Checkbox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_title"  HeaderText="Page Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_description" HeaderText="Page Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_title" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_keywords" HeaderText="Meta Keywords" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_description" HeaderText="Meta Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                        <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:CommandField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Now what my requirement is. Whenever I check the checkbox for any row, and click on the Update button, the repsective `Row` should get open in a popup with the existing data as it is getting for adding the new Row. I tried but couldn't succeed. Please help me with this. Let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks.!

Comment: do you have to use a asp.net gridview?

Comment: Yes I have used a asp.net gridview

Comment: @ScottSelby: Any help sir, needed it

Comment: Are you having problems with the jQuery specifically? The asp.net is hard to parse for me; I might be able to offer a useful answer as long as I can figure out some basics about asp.

Comment: @Malovich: Yes i have a problem with Jquery. I will handle the asp part. Do let me know if you can help in this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ajax`. When you`click on update button` jquery code will look for `checked checkbox` in `gridview`. When it finds this will assign values to `textboxes` placed inside `popup div` from the `row` where checkbox is `checked`.

You have to store `id` in `hidden field` on the basis of which `update query` will run or you can use any field on which `update` will happen.

Now when you `click` on update button in popup an `ajax` call will be sent which will take updated values from `textboxes` and send to `webmethod`.

In `webmethod` you will run your `update` query.And when `ajax` executes successfully you will `reload` the page to see `changes` in `gridview`.

**Html of popup**

```
<div id="Popup">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Category
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="Category" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Items
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="items" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="Openselected()" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" id="hdnID" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

This is not shown as popup but you can use any plugin to show it in popup like blockui,fancybox jqueryui dialog or any one available.

**Jquery Code**

This function will assign values of selected row in textboxes and open popup.

```
function Openselected()
    {
        $('table[id$=grdTest] tr').each(function () {

            if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
                $('#Category').val($(this).children('td').eq('02').text());
                $('#items').val($(this).children('td').eq('03').text());
                $('#hdnID').val($(this).children('td').eq('01').text());
            }


        });
    }
```

This function will send `ajax` call with updated values to `webmethod` and on success `reload` page to see changes.

```
function UpdateGrid()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default.aspx/UpdateDB",
            data: JSON.stringify({ category:$('#Category').val() , items: $('#items').val(),id:$('#hdnID').val() }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Category').val("");
                $('#items').val("");
                $('#hdnID').val("");
                window.location.reload(true);

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }

        });
    }
```

**Here is webmethod**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateDB(string category, string items,int id)
{
    //Your logic of updating db.Here i am updating on basis of id you can use any feild of your choice        
    return "success";

}
```

This is only for one row as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

On the check box selection associate a modal pop up dialog box and populate the same data on any of the command names.

Answer (score 3):

Right, I'll give this a crack.

In PHP-HTML, or just plain old HTML, you can assign data-* attributes to any kind of element. In ASP, I assume you can do something similar. Store the data you want to be available for the dialog box in these data attributes, give the elements all a class ('checkboxDialog') and then the jQuery can do the rest.

CSS

```
.hide {display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dialog-form hide">

    <!-- input elements with id's for easy identification -->

</div>

<table>
    <tr class="checkboxDialog" data-current="current data in elements like this" data-id=1">
        <td><button>Update</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- repeat as necessary -->
</table>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.checkboxDialog').on('click', function(e){ // This attached a click event listener to all matching elements
            var selectedObj = $(this);

            $('#inputCurrent').val(selectedObj.data('current'));
            $('#inputId').val('id'); // etc etc

            $('.dialog-form')
                .removeClass('hide')
                .dialog({ // From the jQuery-ui library, check it out!
                    buttons: {
                        Submit: function(){
                            // You can either submit an actual form, or alter data via AJAX
                            //  and repopulate the row with the new data when the AJAX completes
                            $(this).close();
                        },
                        Cancel: function(){
                            $(this).close();
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Might be a good idea. However, as long as a) I understand what you are actually trying to accomplish and b) you are able to make the HTML markup appear as I've shown it, the code will work. This is a question of understanding what you are actually after.

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery-ui library?

Comment: @Malovuch, yes obviously i have loaded that

Answer (score 2):

Use combination of jQuery & ASP.NET code to address the requirement.

(1) On click of update, through jQuery get the list of all selected (checked) rows.

(2) Do store ID or Unique key for each row (may be Page ID in your case) as hidden field in same row itself.

(3) Now, call javascript window.open() or alternate popup for each selected row.

(4) To populate the controls within popup, you can either pass it as query string parameter or re-fetch them from backend using the hidden field value. You need to create a ASP.NET service to return you those values from Backend.

Comment: Please explain with the code, do let me know if you need anything from my side

Answer (score -1):

Do below steps for getting the row in popup:

1. while attaching datatable to grid view add new column 'RowNo' by code.
2. Update command field by adding js function as per below:

   ```
   <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" onClick="showData(<%#RowNo%>)"  ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
   ```
3. write JS function as per below after including jquery plugin:

   ```
   function showData(rowNo) {
   var html = $('#grdCSRPageData>tbody').find('tr:eq(' + rowNo + ')');
   //div123 is the test div and one should replace this with required one.
   $('#div123').html(html);
   $('#div123').show();
   };
   ```

Answer (score -3):

```
DO it in parts. Use jquery for accessing the checkbox inside the gridview. First give a css class to the checkbox(for helping jquery to find it by this style). Then call the checkbox event handling from the below code-

**if ($('.checkboxCss').prop('checked'))
{
//open the pop up window with the editing fields
}**

Now on the sub`enter code here`mit button click of the pop up window, you can use jquery ajax to call the c# function which do the updation of the record. Here you have to use a static [webmethod] C# function to call it with jquery AJAX.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried it the way u suggested

Comment: did you got success from it ?